# Multiple javax.validation.constraints validations on @PathVariable

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc, javax.validation

I am applying multiple validations on path variable

```
@PathVariable(name = "id")
  @NotBlank(message = "Missing required field")
  @Size(min = 1, max = 3, message = "Invalid input size")
String id
```

Now, when I am sending empty string in path param then I am getting both messages because both validations are failing.

For my param **id**, I want both validations but it should not throw both error messages at a time when I am sending empty string.

I want it to throw only

> "Missing required field"

and not both.

Comment: you can create your own custom validation
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator

Comment: @SasukeUchiha - I tried that but validator's isValid() method returns true/false, which is not solving my multi-validation  problem.

Comment: @MayurGite did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NotBlank` is a combination of both functionalities that `NotNull` and `NotEmpty` validate. Therefore `@NotBlank` will fire both when the bound pathVariable is `null` and when `empty`.

Since you already have `@Size(min = 1, max = 3, message = "Invalid input size")` you are already checking if `not empty`. This annotation will fire at the same time with `@NotBlank` in case the pathVariable is `empty` string.

So you only need a different constraint validation for when it is `null`, so that the 2 annotations that enforce constraints do not override each other.

As a solution you can replace `@NotBlank` with `@NotNull`.

```
@PathVariable(name = "id")
  @NotNull(message = "Missing required field")
  @Size(min = 1, max = 3, message = "Invalid input size")
String id
```